# Updating node without retrieving it first using Neo4j OGM

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm, spring-data-neo4j-5

I have a structure, which (simplified) looks like this:

```
@NodeEntity(label = "Entity")
class FullEntity {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    var _id: Long? = null

    @Id @Index(unique = true)
    lateinit var uuid: String

    lateinit var someMoreData: String // this data is sometimes lost

    @Relationship(type = "TARGETS", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    var target: StubEntity? = null
}

@NodeEntity(label = "Entity")
class StubEntity {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    var _id: Long? = null

    @Id @Index(unique = true)
    lateinit var uuid: String
}

@RepositoryRestResource
interface EntityRepository : Neo4jRepository<FullEntity, Long>
```

Now when I save two related `FullEntity` objects independently, it all works if I do it one way:

```
entityRepository.save(FullEntity().apply {
    uuid = "uuid1"
    someMoreData = "SomeMoreData1"
    target = StubEntity().apply {
        uuid = "uuid2"
    }
})
// some time later ...
entityRepository.save(FullEntity().apply {
    uuid = "uuid2"
    someMoreData = "SomeMoreData2"
})
```

but if I reverse the order like so:

```
entityRepository.save(FullEntity().apply {
    uuid = "uuid2"
    someMoreData = "SomeMoreData2"
})
// some time later ...
entityRepository.save(FullEntity().apply {
    uuid = "uuid1"
    someMoreData = "SomeMoreData1"
    target = StubEntity().apply {
        uuid = "uuid2"
    }
})
```

it removes `"SomeMoreData2"`.

Comment: I can somehow reproduce your problem but need some time to analyse. One thing I noticed is that if you would activate indexes, it won't create the entries since you want uniqueness of the uuid for the `Entity` labeled notes. But you also may help me understanding your use case: Why are you defining multiple `Id` fields?

Comment: @meistermeier I actually have unique constraint (and index too) on this `uuid`. `_id` is internal id in Neo database, which I don't really use anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with your classes and the use in OGM:

1. You use the label `Entity` twice. This will create problems if OGM 
   tries to load the data from Neo4j. It cannot find the right type to assign the values. Possible workarounds:

   - Explicitly set the label to another one like `StubEntity` for this class.
   - If this is not possible because the uniqueness of the uuid over both classes, you may not even need the `StubEntity` but use the `FullEntity` class also for the relationship target. There will be no difference in Neo4j after saving the data.
   - If both classes have more differences than the sample code above shows, you may create an abstract class with the `Entity` label and also provide special type labels (implicit by just annotating with `@NodeEntity` or explicit with the label attribute you are already using) on the implementing classes. Than you could use the uuid constraint in the abstract class.
2. Using the `@Id` annotation twice. There is no need to declare an additional `@Id` on the uuid field if you just need the field in the index and an unique constraint (if I have understood your comment correct).